# EntityFramework.Extended update navigation property

Tags: entity-framework

My code is

```
public void MoveProducts(int currentCategoryId, int newCategoryId)
{
        _dbContext.Products.Update(p => p.Category.ID = newCategoryId);
}
```

The p => p.Category.Id = newCategoryID raised error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'DAL.Models.Product
```

I used EntityFramework.Extended  to perform bulk update.
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you realize there is a stray `}` in your code?

Comment: Oh, my mistake when I post questions. That's not affect to the error